# Spark - Extracting date string from DateType

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Row object which contains one of the column of type DateType.

I am extracting individual field values from this Row object as follows:

```
val eventDate = row.getAs[DateType](0)
val recordCount = row.getAs[Long](1)
```

I want to extract string representation of date value from eventDate. How can I do this? Intellij suggests a method on eventDate named formatted which I used as below:

```
val eventDateString = row.getAs[DateType](0).formatted("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

However, after execution, value in eventDateString is "yyyy-MM-dd" and not the actual value of date. How can I get the actual date value in string representation.

Also, I am not able to find the formatted(format:String) method in the Spark2 documentation at below link. I am wondering why Intellij is showing this method when documentation does not show this method. Please help.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/DateType.html

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
val schema = StructType(List(new StructField("event_date", DateType)))
val data = Seq(Row(Date.valueOf("2018-10-21")), Row(Date.valueOf("2018-10-22")))
val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data), schema)
df.printSchema()
df.show()

//here it will cast date type to string type
df.foreach { row =>
  println(row.getAs[String]("event_date"))
}
```

Sample Output:

```
root
 |-- event_date: date (nullable = true)

+----------+
|event_date|
+----------+
|2018-10-21|
|2018-10-22|
+----------+

2018-10-21
2018-10-22
```

Note: Tested with Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11.8

Comment: Thanks, please refer answer below. I am getting an exception with the cast.

Comment: Can you try this? println(row.getAs[Date]("event_date").toString()). Both ways worked fine for me. Can you give the Scala and spark versions that you are working? So that I will try to simulate the same error. @Ankur